# How to add more information in the title page of beamer presentation in R markdown?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown, page-title

I tried like this method,

```
title: "Course"
author: |
        |           %email:
        |           %office
output: 
  beamer_presentation
```

But, it will show all the information of block "author" in the Lower left corner in each slide.

I hope to get the result like,

```
This is the title

Author

email:
office:

Date
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could set a short author option of `\author[short form for footline]{long form for titlepage}` to modify the text shown in the footline:

```
---
title: "Course"
author: |
        |           %email:
        |           %office
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: Dresden
header-includes:
   - \AtBeginDocument{\author[Author]{Author\\ email:\\ office:}}
---

test
```

[image]

Comment: how can I hide author name in footer of each slide which is by default gets printed if I use any theme?

Comment: @krushnachChandra If you are able to create a short example that demonstrates your problem and shows which theme you use, you could ask a question at https://topanswers.xyz/tex I'm sure this can be solved easily.